# Customized Listview in android

Tags: android, xml

I am trying the customized Listview in my android application. The problem is I have given the background image for the listview.In samsung galaxy S and nexus one the background is showing between the divider space in the listview but in Samsung Galaxy grand and Galaxy Nexus the background image is not coming.

Can anybody let me know the problem?

This is my main.xml

```
<LinearLayout 
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:background="@drawable/mainbackground"
       android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
       android:id="@android:id/list"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:dividerHeight="10.0dp"
       android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

This list_row.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
android:padding="5dip" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_image"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/no_image" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="20dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="sans" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Age"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/Name"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="15dip" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Phone_number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/Age"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:text="Promotion:"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="15dip" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/number"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/Age"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Phone_number"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="15dip" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/arrow" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

This is my list_selector.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item
     android:state_selected="false"
     android:state_pressed="false"
     android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg" />
 <item android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover" />
 <item android:state_selected="true"
      android:state_pressed="false"
      android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover" />
 </selector>
```

Comment: remove decimal in the divider height and then try

Comment: I tried it is the same

Comment: another thing you  can do is in the image if you put some transparent area in the below part it would solve your problem